# How can I stream video from Android to Node using websockets?

Tags: java, android, node.js, websocket, video-streaming

I have a basic echo message app running on Android using example code from the libs I'm using. From the android client, it is sending to the server using Autobahn (http://autobahn.ws/android/) and accepting the connection with sockjs (https://github.com/sockjs/sockjs-node) library on a node server.

I'm trying to stream video from Android to the node server via websockets.

I'm aware of how to stream to a server via TCP or UDP using the ParcelFileDescriptor class.
Autobahn has a sendBinaryMessage (byte[] payload) method, so it can send binary data.

Is it possible to do something similar with websockets? If so, what is the best approach?